# Convert a message object to a string with emojis with discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, emoji, discord.py

I'm trying to create a bot in python which record every messages on a server in a .txt file

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    id = client.get_guild(Server ID)
    f= open('logs_messages.txt','a+')
    f.write(f'{message.author.id} \n \n')
    f.write(f'Date et heure {datetime.now()} \n \n')
    f.write(f'ID du channel:<#{message.channel.id}> \n \n')
    f.write(f'{message.content} \n \n \n \n')
    f.close
```

So the code is working, execpt when the message contains an emoji the program doesn't write anything and return this:

```
File "C:\Users\psg97\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bot.py", line 37, in on_message
    f.write(f'{message.content} \n \n \n \n')
  File "C:\Users\psg97\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f389' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

Does anyone knows how can I convert these emojis in a way that i can write them in the .txt file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encode your content to `utf-8` using

```
f.write(f'{message.content.encode('utf8')} \n \n \n \n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open whole file with `utf-8` encode:

```
with open('logs_messages.txt','a+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(f'{message.author.id} \n \n')
    f.write(f'Date et heure {datetime.now()} \n \n')
    f.write(f'ID du channel:<#{message.channel.id}> \n \n')
    f.write(f'{message.content} \n \n \n \n')
    f.close
```